# SQL group by into a pivot

Tags: sql, pivot

I can do this on my table:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY country, type
```

This query gives me

```
country    type     COUNT(*)
Canada     first    22
Canada     second   42
Canada     third    15
Australia  second   23
Australia  third    18
```

but I need to get

```
country    first   second   third
Canada     22      42       15
Australia  23      18       0
```

Complexity is, 3 columns here just an example; and have about 20 different; and I have over 200 countries... I have found something like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28406/group-by-two-columns?newreg=febbf51c648e4c17a2ebcb798bff1261, but # of columns I'd end up is rendering this approach infeasible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL then you already know the answer from the link.

In SQL server you can do this.

```
SELECT  country, [First],[Second],[Third]
FROM  
(
    SELECT country, [type],COUNT(*)cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY country, [type]
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
max(cnt)  
FOR [type] IN ([First],[Second],[Third])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

And please share your table structure with sample data for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. The type column has about 250 different groups. Would I still need to do SELECT  country, [First],[Second],[Third]...[250]?

Comment: Please let me know which dbms are you using to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
select country,
       sum(case when type = 'first' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_first,
       sum(case when type = 'second' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_second,
       . . .
from t
group by country;
```

You may find that generating the `sum(case)` expressions is more easily done in a spreadsheet then typing them out (although copy and paste is really pretty simple for 20 rows).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, is there a work around if the number of cases I have is over 200.

Comment: @AtaSagun . . . As I say in the question, it is a simple matter to copy the types into a spreadsheet and generate the code there.

Answer (score 0):

The pivoting style for a select statement is closely related with the DBMS been used. Presuming the DBMS you're using as MySQL depending on the shared link within the question, use

```
SELECT country, SUM(type='first') AS first,
                SUM(type='second') AS second,
                SUM(type='third') AS third 
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY country
```

as a static query, and that could be converted to the following code block in order to make it dynamic

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                    'SUM(type="',type,'" ) AS ',type
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT type FROM table1 ) AS t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT country,',@sql,' FROM table1 GROUP BY country'); 
                  
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd85ea7da1cd70fd19c9be21de20ccbc)</kbd>